# Preprocessing of Javascript files in Yii2 application

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I have Javascript files in my Yii2 (advanced template) project and I'm finding that my Javascript files are filling up with hard coded url paths and the names of model fields (converted into dom/jquery selectors).

Previously I have been including the Javascript files in the page by rendering them with a controller/view and hard coding them into the layout files.

The project has got bigger and now I'm using asset bundles, but it appears that I can only use asset bundles for "pure" javascript files. I still have to serve the others through Yii2.

I think that this is probably an enterprise problem, so how do other people tackle this issue.

Do you have a separate javascript page model then include a registerJS snippet to copy the page model into the yii model, or do you run preprocessing tools on the Javascript files and save them. How does't this work with bundling and compressing the assets for production use.

Any guidance, enterprise patterns or yii2 best practice help would be gratefully received.

Comment: i am trying to understand that if you are having problem with compressing the assets or using files like `.sas` and `.map` to be included in the assets manager , and the very first paragraph of your question what does it mean by **my Javascript files are filling up with hard coded url paths and the names of model fields (converted into dom/jquery selectors).**?

Comment: Is hard to understand what you are asking. Do you need to pass dynamic values from php to Javascript? If so you can write JS variables on your php files or assign values to the `data-` attribute of related HTML elements.